# Can a dedicated router recevie and send messages at the same time?

Tags: router

I know each time only one packet can be sent or received by a dedicated router. But can it do the two job at the same time?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. On a single core processor, no, on a multi core processor, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same path. Technically not, unless it sends and receives on two different frequencies. Otherwise it would not be able to distinguish between signals its sending and ones being received. More specifics would depend on the make and model of the router. This is called simultaneous data transfer but usually refers to sending on 2 different frequencies as in duel band simultaneous data transfer.

Comment: If in this case: A dedicated router C connects two terminals A and B, A transfer data to B through C. Could C sends data to B while receives data from A at the same time?

Comment: Yes. But again, depends on the router being used. Some can, others cant.

Comment: So we are talking about _wireless_ routers? If so, that was a rather important detail missing from the question.

Comment: Some wireless routers can also transmit on two different frequencies simultaneously.

Comment: @Rapidturtle: I noticed you have asked many questions but not accepted any answers. If you accept the answer given, please select the tick image for that answer. I only recently figured this out myself. XD